# flat surfaces become "waved" using stereo_image_proc

Tags: stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

using stereo_image_proc I observe that flat surfaces appear waved in the
resulting point cloud - with growing "wavelength" for farer points. Is this
because of the quadratic interpolation done by stereo_image_proc for subpixel
accurancy? Is there any option to reduce this effect (which is really bad for
drivability analysis)?

Curious about your answers,
Sabrina

P. S. I also posted these questions on the ros-users mailing list.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9459/flat-surfaces-become-%22waved%22-using-stereo_image_proc/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some more tests I found out that this seems to be an issue related to texture rendering in our 3D simulator (not gazebo) that I am using.  With our real stereo cam this effect is hardly visible. Thus it is not a stereo_image_proc specific problem.

---

Originally posted by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) with karma: 285 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Sabrina,

IMHO, this is perfectly normal in the context of stereography. As you say, it is due to the quadratic interpolation done by stereo_image_proc.

Have a look at chapter 12 of the book "learning openCV", it explains this process.
In the main line, the problem is that there is a nonlinear relationship between the disparity (distance in pixel between left and right image) and the real distance.

Did you try following this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters) on tuning stereo_proc parameters?

Hope it helps

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Raph,

I already looked closely at the parameters (and the corresponding source code) for pre and post-processing and the Open CV's Stereo Block Matcher. I don't see any possibility to reduce the wave effect with these parameters.

I am also playing around with a Kinect which is quite interesting for indoor applications but for outdoor usage the kinect is not suitable in my experience.

Regards,
Sabrina

---

Originally posted by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) with karma: 285 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2011-03-17**:
sabrina-this seems but definitely too noisy. Could you upload some bags with the data representing your artifacts? d.

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2011-03-17**:
I thought about something like this as well. But  the problem is that I want to use the stereo camera for obstacle detection and I can't distinguish between real (maybe small) obstacles on the ground and the waves created by interpolation. Thus segmenting planes would not solve my problem.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-17**:
I indicated a few other stereo processing packages on your other post. I hope you can find something better but I somehow feel you are reaching the limits of stereoscopy itself. I am curious to hear a specialist's opinion.  One work around could be to use pcl to detect the flat surfaces and somehow adverage the points in them. (check http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials/Planar%20model%20segmentation)